# Сломались стили после переноса сайта wp

Tags: wordpress

Перенес сайт с одного домена на другой. Базу данных перенес по инструкции https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/spravka-po-cms/perenos-sayta-na-wordpress-s-odnogo-domena-na-drugoy
Сайт заработал, но админка выглядит как на скрине ниже
[image: Неисправная админка]

Вот пример админки до переноса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как работают стили админки в wp, так что понятия не имею от чего оттолкнуться. Написано, что они заданы файлом php, может он их подгружает от куда-то(догадка)

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Надо читать StackOverflow, а не непрофессиональные инструкции на reg.ru: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в стилях админки. Из девственного wordpress взял папку css в папке wp-admin и заменил ее. После этого все заработало

Answer (score -1):

Возможно вы использовали скачали и заливали файлы на сервер через FTP, и вы могли залить файлы используя НЕ двоичный тип передачи данных.

Попробуйте выставить режим передачи двоичный.
После этого скачать файлы и залить их снова

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я заливал zip архив и распаковал его на хостинге, это могло как-то повлиять?

Comment: @Кирилл А как вы архивировали?
Скачайте wp нужной версии с офф сайта и залейте на сервер папки wp-admin и wp-includes

Заливайте через ftp используя режим передачи двоичный
Все по идее должно заработать

Comment: выделил все и поставил архивироваться через winrar

Comment: @Кирилл читай по ссылке KaggDesing-a, а не эту безграмотность.

Comment: @Кирилл по поводу безграмотности почитайте ответ который написал автор и потом прочитайте что я писал автору в комментарии.