# WP выводит код на страницу

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, база-данных, apache2

Сделал дома локальный сервер, привязал домен, закинул файлы сайта, переделал БД под новый домен, теперь сайт выводит непонятный код. Сайт на домене [inettrafic.ru](http://inettrafic.ru)
На локальном хостинге на компе все работает хорошо. До этого стоял чистый wp и в е нормально работало

Comment: Зачем давать ссылку на сайт, доступ на который запрещён? Как переносили сайт (интересует значение этой фразы "переделал БД под новый домен,")?

Comment: проблему уже решил

Answer (score 0):

добавить в php.ini

```
short_open_tag=on
```

Comment: Не рекомендуется к использованию стандартами кодирования WordPress, потому что запрещён на многих хостингах. Если сервер ваш и сайт потом не придётся никуда переносить, то можно использовать.

Comment: @KAGGDesign после "выводит непонятный код" и вообще манипуляций аля "закинул файлы сайта, переделал БД" ничего удивительного. ТСа ждёт ещё много удивительных открытий :) Он же не слушает правильных советов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055259/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-wp